# In React how to stop rendering components which state or props not changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got an issue in my project , that I had a main component which acts as the parent component of my project inside that I had the routes for the other components and some other component which are directly imported into it like a **Side Navbar** **Component and Login Component** so which are triggered on an event button click , but when I open those components all the other components are re-rendering .

```
    export const AppFramework = (props) => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const [isSideNav, setIsSideNav] = useState(false);
    const OptimizedRoutes = React.memo(AppRoutes);

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log('AppFramework Mounted');
    }, []);


// Methods For Opening and closing of Login and SideNav

    const handleOpen = useCallback(() => {
      setIsOpen(true);
    }, [isOpen]);
    const handleClose = useCallback(() => {
      setIsOpen(false);
    }, [isOpen]);
    const openSideNav = useCallback(() => {
      return setIsSideNav(true);
    }, [isSideNav]);
  
    
    const LoginPopBody = (
      <div className="pop-window">
        <Button startIcon={<Close />} onClick={handleClose}></Button>
        {/* {For Fields for loggin in .........} */}
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <Router>
        <HideOnScroll>
          <AppBar color="default" className="app-header">
            <Button startIcon={<Menu />} onClick={openSideNav}></Button>    // Button To Open Side Navbar 
            <Button onClick={handleOpen}>Login</Button>                     /* Button To Open Login Popup */
          </AppBar>
        </HideOnScroll>

//sidenav comp passing props to open and close below 

        <SideNav open={isSideNav} close={setIsSideNav} /> 

//routes are below 
        <main className="main-blk">
          <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
            <OptimizedRoutes />
          </Suspense>
        </main>
        <Modal open={handleOpen}>{LoginPopBody} </Modal>
      </Router>
    );
  };
  export default React.memo(AppFramework);
```

On opening and closing of both login popup and side navbar renders every component .I tried **React.memo** in each component but nothing happened , I hope hooks will give a solution for this.

And one more thing while entering **each input on login popup form fields also renders every components** behind the login popup . what will be the solution for these issues ?

Comment: Where did you try to use `React.memo` HOC? Did you also provide a second argument to is, the custom `isEqual` function that compares previous and next props? It's also not a guarantee to prevent rerendering. Nothing in React is really. This component rerenders when you update/toggle any of the `isOpen` or `isSideNav` state, which rerenders all children. Is there an issue with the rerenders? As in, is there some adverse effect because of it?

Comment: while exporting each component i wrapped it by `React.memo` . No I didn't heard about `isEqual` function  can you share any documents to go through it  and there is a not a big issue on that rendering but it looks weird to look on that because I have slides behind  that so every time  when i open the side navbar or login it refreshes the whole page . So its a kind of performance issue right ?

Comment: Nothing like good old official [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo). "Kind of a performance issue" is a fairly subjective thing. Generally I think it's recommended to let React render when React renders, and only then if you detect *actual* measurable performance degredation do you reach for the optimization tools. Believe it or not, React is optimized quite well out-of-the-box. This isn't to say that your UI maybe won't have some quicks if you composed them oddly. Since the callback is the only prop passed to them I don't think `memo` will help any TBH.

Comment: yeah even i have odd opinion in my component design and even i have used the `useCallback` hook wrongly because the the prop passed will definetly makes it render again , I thought someone will point out my mistake where I did ! ok i was going through the docs now , I hope will find a solution for this.

Comment: the dependency would be in an infinite state of toggling between false and true. putting a checking under both handleOpen and handleClose would handle that.

Comment: @visizky can you point out the mistake where I did ?  because I'm a beginner , anyway I solved the issue temporarily  now but I would like to get a proper solution. because I don't want to get into this kind of problem in future.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you are satisfied with but most of the time these problems pop up because of the way you design/construct your components. In react planning the components is the first and in my opinion the most important thing. It can save us from a lot of trouble. In this case You need to keep the components linked but independent of each other.

I would recommend you to read https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html. This might help you.

Changing the state will definitely re-render the whole component. But to avoid some components to stop re-rendering or re-render on come custom state changes you can use `useCallBack` hook.

The following article might help.

https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback/

You can put the other component in individual functions and use useCallback hook on those function. This way you can define on which state change should those functions be used again.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue is resolved , actually my problem is very simple , its not a complicated problem , To open the **Side Navbar and Login Component** I don't need to pass a boolean value from the parent component as a **Prop** .

Instead of that, we can get the boolean value from the own component by a passing a boolean value to the module to be shown in my case I used **Material UI's Modal and Drawer**  by an event like button click or any other event .

This is what I did to solve my issue . In short I made the components independent.